# Can I Protect Scripts in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google spreadsheet that I need some people to edit certain parts, so they need edit permission. I have locks on virtually everything else (except things like adding a sheet, but that won't break anything). The problem is that I use quite a few scripts, and I don't know how to block these users from editing them. Is there any way to protect these scripts from being edited from everyone except me?

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why this question hasn't got a decent answer yet after more than 4 years.

It's surprisingly simple :-) Just create a new script (standalone, or under another spreadsheet), and replace all the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` calls by `SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet-id")` in which the spreadsheet-id is the last part of the document URL; `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheet-id}`

Using this easy trick, you access the shared spreadsheet by your own script that is not accessible to the others.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but for anyone coming across this question in the future, my workaround for this was to use a standalone script. Triggers can be created programmatically using the spreadsheet ID (instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)).

Original post: [How can I protect an Apps Script with triggers and authorizations in a shared Google Sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/109073/how-can-i-protect-an-apps-script-with-triggers-and-authorizations-in-a-shared-go)

Answer (score 1):

Bounded projects inherit permissions from the container so users with edit access to the spreadsheet will have edit access to the code in the bounded project.

One alternative to protect the code from editing is to move it to another project to be used as a library.
Another alternative is to create an add-on.

---

**References**

[Collaborating with Other Developers - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/collaborating)